# Simple Server Node.js return html page

Tags: node.js

I am trying to run a local server on Node.js that returns a simple html page. The difficulty for me at this point is understanding how to make the file system handle function correctly.. I am looking for the right code to use when the /recipe extension is called in the browser.

I get the error "no such file or directory", while the path they specify is correct. There is a file in there with the correct name..

Do I have to manually add "fs" in npm? 
Is there another mistake in my code?
Am I forgetting something?

I have the following code:

```
// strict mode catches javascript errors better.. 
"use strict"; 

// localhost port on which you can access the application in DEV 
// http status codes accesses npm package that contains main API status codes 
// fs is the file system handler to handle the html files 
const port = 3000,
http = require("http"),
httpStatus = require("http-status-codes"), 
app = http.createServer(),
fs = require("fs");

// set up route mapping for html file
const routeResponseMap = {

    "/recipe": "view/recipe.html",
    "/index": "<h2>this is the index page</h2>"

};

// need to open your browser localhost:port for the request to be made.. 
app.on("request", (request,response) => {

    response.writeHead(httpStatus.OK, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});

    if(routeResponseMap[request.url]){

        response.end(routeResponseMap[request.url]);

        if(routesResponse[request.url]){


            // the error is here, file does not get read
            // WHAT CODE DO I NEED HERE?
            fs.readFile(routesResponse[request.url]), (error, data) => {

            response.write(data);
            response.end();
        }

        console.log("route in mapping");

        }

        else{

            response.end("<h3>Sorry not found</h3>");

        }
    })

app.listen(port);
console.log("The server has started and is listening on port " + port);
```

Comment: the /index functions as it should, when clicking /recipe the html file does not get called.. I see the correct path appearing on console, but the html file does not show..

Comment: The error is the first `response.end()` which ends the HTTP connection. Everything after that will be ignored by the browser (I don't think they will even be sent)